# Google maps api filter checkbox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make google map with filtering. One filter is select box (for now it is working) and other filer is with check boxes. So now my it have behavior as a radio button. You can se example here http://extrol.ellectadigital.com/distributeri/. 

When you check it, it shows good pin, but when you click on the second it removes the first pin, and I don't want that. 
So here is my code :

```
`http://codepen.io/PoznanM/pen/VpoZOm`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is here `onclick="filterChecker(this.value);"` in `filterChecker` function only single checked item was compared and other marker are cleared.

So you have to compare  all the checked items. I added function `selectAllChecked()` which passes checked values as array to  function `filterChecker()`

```js
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: ''
});
var filters = {
  shower: false,
  vault: false,
  flush: false
}

// Our markers
markers1 = [
  ['0', 'Title', 44.741318, 20.433573, 'Beograd', 'distributer'],
  ['1', 'Title', 45.823783, 16.024404, 'Zagreb', 'servis'],
  ['2', 'Title', 44.438350, 17.631215, 'Bosna', 'maloprodaja']
];

/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(45.662477, 18.022074);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.662477, 18.022074),
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    addMarker(markers1[i]);
  }
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
  var tip = marker[5];
  var category = marker[4];
  var title = marker[1];
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
  var content = marker[1];

  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: title,
    position: pos,
    tip: tip,
    category: category,
    map: map
  });

  gmarkers1.push(marker1);

  // Marker click listener
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, content) {
    return function() {
      console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
      infowindow.setContent(content);
      infowindow.open(map, marker1);
      map.panTo(this.getPosition());
      map.setZoom(15);
    }
  })(marker1, content));
}

/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
 */

filterMarkers = function(category) {
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    // If is same category or category not picked
    if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
      marker.setVisible(true);
    }
    // Categories don't match
    else {
      marker.setVisible(false);
    }
  }

}
var get_set_options = function() {
  ret_array = []
  for (option in filters) {
    if (filters[option]) {
      ret_array.push(option)
    }
  }
  return ret_array;
}

var filter_markers = function() {
  set_filters = get_set_options()

  // for each marker, check to see if all required options are set
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    marker = markers[i];

    // start the filter check assuming the marker will be displayed
    // if any of the required features are missing, set 'keep' to false
    // to discard this marker
    keep = true
    for (opt = 0; opt < set_filters.length; opt++) {
      if (!marker.properties[set_filters[opt]]) {
        keep = false;
      }
    }
    marker.setVisible(keep)
  }
}


// Fuction for checkboxes
var tipovi = document.getElementsByClassName('chk-btn').value;

var selectAllChecked = function() {
  var checkedPlace = [] 
  var allCheckedElem = document.getElementsByName('filter');
  for (var i = 0; i < allCheckedElem.length; i++) {
    if (allCheckedElem[i].checked == true) {
      checkedPlace.push(allCheckedElem[i].value)//creating array of checked items
    }
  }
  filterChecker(checkedPlace) //passing to function for updating markers
}

var filterChecker = function(tip) {
  //console.log(tip);
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    //console.log(marker);
    if (in_array(this.marker.tip, tip) != -1) {
      marker.setVisible(true);
    } else {
      marker.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}
// Init map
initialize();

function in_array(needle, haystack) {
  var found = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = haystack.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (haystack[i] == needle) return i;
    found++;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 300px;
}

#iw_container .iw_title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.iw_content {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas">

</div>

<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
  <option value="">Izaberite Mesto</option>
  <option value="Beograd">Beograd</option>
  <option value="Zagreb">Zagreb</option>
  <option value="Bosna">Bosna</option>
</select>
<div id="buttons">

  <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="distributer" class='chk-btn' onclick="selectAllChecked();">
  <label for='shower'>Distributer</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="maloprodaja" class='chk-btn' onclick="selectAllChecked();">
  <label for='flush'>Maloprodaja</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="servis" class='chk-btn' onclick="selectAllChecked();">
  <label for='vault'>Servis</label>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCmUfKutqGZ-VgbD4fwjOFd1EGxLXbxcpQ&sCensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you for explanation and answer!